# Post Types, Taxonomies and routing

Tags: wordpress, routes, taxonomy

I'm ready to give up on Wordpress.

I've got this issue. I have created a custom post-type via wp-types plugin. I can display it and display posts from it.

However, I have created a custom page with a custom template that renders the posts. I have done so because the site uses multiple languages, and I needed the url to be in that specific language.

Thus the post-type is not displayed through the standard **archive-{post-type-name}.php** file, but instead a custom template and a custom wordpress page.
Just because I need the urls to be in the same language as the given page language, example:

```
myurl.com/{name_in_one_language} 
and 
myurl.com/{name_in_another_language}
```

The issue with that is that my custom post-type has custom taxonomies attached to it. Before the posts are rendered I select the taxonomy and then render the rest of the page based on the taxonomy name. Example:

```
myurl.com/paintings/?category=category_name 
|| or || 
myurl.com/paintings/?author=painting_author
```

The thing is that the client doesn't like that kind of custom url parameters. He is begging for me to change it to the following format:

```
myurl.com/paintings/{taxonomy}/{painting}
```

Where taxonomy is either authors name or art type. And the paintings page itself is just a middleware to select which post with the needed taxonomy needs to be displayed.

I have ran out of ideas of how to do it. Completely.

I tried going with the **archive-{post-type-name}.php** solution, have no clue how wp-types plugin rewrite works. Tried using the wordpress permalink syntax in the plugin, doesn't recognize it.

Basically what I need is the following: For my custom page that has a custom template that renders custom post-type with custom taxonomies to route in the following way:

```
myurl.com/{page-with-template-that-renders-custom-post-type}/{post-type-taxonomy}/{post}
```

I really find Wordpress difficult to work with, the way you have to inject code, handle routes, register types. It feels like you're just patching it together to make a horrible monster that spews code bile over everyone.

Answer (score 0):

First, set your permalink settings to 'Post name'. Read through Wordpress' template hierarchy to understand how things work: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

If you create a taxonomy-{taxonomy-slug}.php template, you can then navigate to myurl.com/paintings/{taxonomy}/{taxonomy-term} and use the following within your template

```
$taxonomy = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$term = get_query_var( 'term' );
```

.. and use those variables in your query.

A single-{post-type-slug}.php would be used to render the post itself.

I would argue that it is not advisable to include the taxonomy in the URL of the post as these could change, or you could have multiple terms associated with a post. But, if it's necessary, check out this article: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-taxonomy-tags-to-your-wordpress-permalinks